# ActiveRecord: Find parent where none of the children meet a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to use Active Record to find parents where none of the children meet a certain condition.

In my application, users can post *Bids* on *Items*. One bid is set as the winner via a `status` enum. **I'm trying to return a list of the items that do not have a winning bid.**

Here's the relevant code:

```
# item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
  scope :without_winner, -> { joins(:bids).where.not(bids: { status: :won }) }
end


# bid.rb
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  enum status: { pending: 0, won: 1, lost: 2 }
end
```

My problem is that the current `:without_winner` scope will return an item *every time* it has a non-winning bid. For instance, if we have two Items with three Bids each:

```
Item 1
  Bid 1 (won)
  Bid 2 (lost)
  Bid 3 (lost)

Item 2
  Bid 4 (pending)
  Bid 5 (pending)
  Bid 6 (pending)
```

My current `:without_winner` scope would return Item 1 twice and Item 2 three times. My desired output would simply return Item 2 once, and not return Item 1 at all.

How can I correct my scope to return a list of unique items without a winning bid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used a scope in a while although it's an awesome syntactic sugar. But If you're really stuck, you can try the class method below. It looks ugly, but the good thing is it fires only one query and filters according to your requirement.

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids

  def self.without_winner
    includes(:bids).joins(:bids).distinct.reject do |item|
      item.bids.pluck(:status).include? :won
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.distinct` to your scope to weed out the duplicates:

```
scope :without_winner, -> { joins(:bids).where.not(bids: { status: :won }).distinct }
```

Comment: `.distinct` is very cool, thanks! This solves the uniqueness problem, but still returns items with winning bids if they have a losing bid. See the example in my original question – "My desired output would simply return Item 2 once, and not return Item 1 at all."